# Is it possible to confirm before publishing in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, plugins, dialog, publish, confirmation

In Visual Studio, we're using the click-to-publish thingy... is it possible to write a plugin or somehow give a confirmation dialog when you click publish to make sure that's what you want to do? don't want people accidentally overwriting production

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is it possible to turn this on by default, but if not - at first you need to understand how VS does this. Probably this is some msbuild targets file (msbuild task) which has some settings like "Publish = True/False". So what you can do - is to create a new msbuild task which you will invoke before the Publish task (you can try to add this task to your project file). In your task you will check if "Publish = True" - you will show message box "Do you want to publish?" and if somebody will click No, you just need to override "Publish" value in msbuild to False. I think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any plugin which can do this.

One approach to mitigate the risks would be to create multiple configurations combined with multiple publish profiles:

E.g.

- configurations: Debug_Development, Release_Development,
  Release_Production where, using [web.config transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx), set
  different settings for connection strings, app settings, etc. (a nice
  introduction to web.config transforms, and not only, can be found
  [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/01/17/10-things-asp-net-developers-should-know-about-web-config-inheritance-and-overrides.aspx))
- publish profiles: debug_development, release_development and release_production, each of them with different ftp settings (if you deploy via ftp) and each of them connected to the corresponding configuration